# equilibrium points is a discrete set

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations

$$\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
x'(t) = y(t)\\
y'(t) = -W'(x(t))
\end{array}
\right.$$
where $W : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^+, (x, y) \mapsto \frac{y^2}{2} + W(x)$ a $\mathcal C^2$ function and it's the first integral of the system.

The equilibrium points are $E = \{ (x, y)\in \mathbb R^2 \ | \ y = 0 \text{ and } W'(x) = 0\}$

Suppose $\forall (x, y) \in E, W''(x) \ne 0$, show that $E$ is discret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $E$ has a limit point $x_0$ which is finite, namely there exists $\{x_n\}\subset E$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0$.  Then
$$ W'(x_n)=0, \forall n\in N $$
from which one has
$$ \frac{W'(x_m)-W'(x_n)}{x_m-x_n}=0, \forall m,n\in N.$$
Letting $m,n\to\infty$ gives
$$ W''(x_0)=0$$
which is against the assumption $W''(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in E$.

Comment: Is it possible to prove without using the boundedness of $E$ ? Because it is supposed to be the next question...

Comment: Here the boundedness is not used.